# Casting a new derived column in a DataFrame from boolean to integer

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a DataFrame `x` with this schema:

```
xSchema = StructType([ \
    StructField("a", DoubleType(), True), \
    StructField("b", DoubleType(), True), \
    StructField("c", DoubleType(), True)])
```

I then have the DataFrame:

```
DataFrame[a :double, b:double, c:double]
```

I would like to have an integer derived column. I am able to create a boolean column:

```
x = x.withColumn('y', (x.a-x.b)/x.c > 1)
```

My new schema is:

```
DataFrame[a :double, b:double, c:double, y: boolean]
```

However, I would like column `y` to contain 0 for False and 1 for True.

The `cast` function can only operate on a column and not a `DataFrame` and the `withColumn` function can only operate on a `DataFrame`. How to I add a new column and cast it to integer at the same time?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Expression you use evaluates to column so you can cast directly like this:

```
x.withColumn('y', ((x.a-x.b) / x.c > 1).cast('integer')) # Or IntegerType()
```