# Transform Boolean Column to Numerical Column in Apache Spark (Scala) data frame with constraints?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

```
 val inputfile = sqlContext.read
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("header", "true") 
        .option("inferSchema", "true") 
        .option("delimiter", "\t")
        .load("data")
 inputfile: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: string, b: bigint, c: boolean]
 val outputfile = inputfile.groupBy($"a",$"b").max($"c")
```

Above code fails because `c` is a boolean variable and aggregates cannot be applied to booleans. Is there a function in Spark that converts `true` value to `1` and `false` to `0` for the full column of Spark data frame.

I tried the following (Source: [How to change column types in Spark SQL's DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383107/how-to-change-column-types-in-spark-sqls-dataframe/33423959) )

```
 val inputfile = sqlContext.read
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("header", "true") 
        .option("inferSchema", "true") 
        .option("delimiter", "\t")
        .load("data")
 val tempfile =inputfile.select("a","b","c").withColumn("c",toInt(inputfile("c")))   
 val outputfile = tempfile.groupBy($"a",$"b").max($"c")
```

Following question: [Casting a new derived column in a DataFrame from boolean to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354571/casting-a-new-derived-column-in-a-dataframe-from-boolean-to-integer) answers for PySpark but I wanted a function specifically for Scala.

Appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
implicit def bool2int(b:Boolean) = if (b) 1 else 0

scala> false:Int
res4: Int = 0

scala> true:Int
res5: Int = 1

scala> val b=true
b: Boolean = true


scala> 2*b+1
res2: Int = 3
```

Use the above function and register as UDF

```
val bool2int_udf = udf(bool2int _)

val tempfile =inputfile.select("a","b","c").withColumn("c",bool2int_UDF($("c")))
```

Comment: Hi @Achyuth, Thanks for looking into this problem. But this does not work. Bool2int is a function which takes in as `bool` as an argument but I needed `org.apache.spark.sql.Column` as the argument.

Comment: UDFs should be last result since they are less efficient. Casting is the better option here.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to use a udf to do this. If you want to convert boolean values to `int`, you can typecast the column to `int`

```
val df2 = df1
  .withColumn("boolAsInt",$"bool".cast("Int")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me. @Achyuth's answer provided the partial function. Then, taking ideas from this question: [Applying function to Spark Dataframe Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35227568/applying-function-to-spark-dataframe-column)
I was able to apply function from Achyuth answer to the full column of the data frame using `UDF`. Here is the full code.

```
 implicit def bool2int(b:Boolean) = if (b) 1 else 0
 val bool2int_udf = udf(bool2int _)
 val inputfile = sqlContext.read
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("header", "true") 
        .option("inferSchema", "true") 
        .option("delimiter", "\t")
        .load("data") 
 val tempfile = inputfile.select("a","b","c").withColumn("c",bool2int_udf($"c"))
 val outputfile = tempfile.groupBy($"a",$"b").max($"c")
```